# Check if time expression fall inside of time range that crosses over midnight

Tags: php, time, date-range

I have following code I am trying to compare two get in order to get into if statement but I something wrong with is code.

**the following code should run if the time is above 23:29 and less then 08:10...**

```
$gettime = "04:39"; // getting this from database

$startdate = strtotime("23:29");
$startdate1 = date("H:i", $startdate);

$enddate = strtotime("08:10");
$enddate1 = date("H:i", $enddate);

if ($gettime >= strtotime($startdate1) && $gettime <= strtotime($enddate1)) {
    echo "ok working";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your comaring the right types of data, time stamps with time stamps and not w/ strings etc...

```
$gettime= strtotime("22:00"); // getting this from database

$startdate = strtotime("21:00");
//$startdate1 = date("H:i", $startdate);

$enddate = strtotime("23:00");
//$enddate1 = date("H:i", $enddate);


//this condition i need to run    

if($gettime >= $startdate && $gettime <= $enddate)
{
echo"ok working";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the string with a date.
$gettime is a string and you are comparing it with a time object.

You need to convert $gettime to a time object by calling $gettime = strtotime($gettime), and then you can compare it using > or < like you have above.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're receiving the time from the DB in a `date` format (and not as a `string`):

change:

```
if($gettime >= strtotime($startdate1) && $gettime <= strtotime($enddate1))
```

to:

```
if($gettime >= strtotime($startdate1) || $gettime <= strtotime($enddate1))
```

Answer (score 0):

For comparing times, you should use the provided PHP classes
The DateTime::diff will return an object with time difference info:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to PHP documentation about `DateTime::diff` function at their website http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

You may also go through this stackoverflow question **[How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)**