# Compare two dates in PHP not compare correctly

Tags: php, date

I Want how to compare two dates

I have this

```
$last_day = '2017-11-01';
$end = '18/03/2017';
$last_day = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($last_day));

            if($last_day < $end){
                echo "Is closed";
            }else{
                echo "Is Open";
            }
```

Return "Is Close"

What happens?

Comment: what is `$fechas['last_day']`?

Comment: what's happening here : `$last_day = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($fechas['last_day']));`

Comment: this is not a date `$last_day = '2017-11-01';`

Comment: you're overwriting `$last_day` in the second pass here. question's unclear as per other comment given up there.

Comment: @Loko they just Stealthly [edited](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42857496/2) that out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php - comparing two date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233436/php-comparing-two-date)

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing strings, not dates. Use DateTime() objects as they are comparable:

```
$last_day = new DateTime('2017-11-01');
$end      = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '18/03/2017');

if($last_day < $end){
  echo "Is closed";
}else{
  echo "Is Open";
}
```

If `$fechas['last_day']` is in `d/m/Y` format you will have to change `$last_day` to use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` as well as that format will cause errors as dates using `/` are considered American and 18/3/2017 would be an invalid date.

Comment: *`If $fechas['last_day']`* - [See my comment...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857496/compare-two-dates-in-php-not-compare-correctly#comment72821142_42857496) John.

Answer (score 0):

You are not compare two dates in `date` format. 
Please convert first in `strtotime` format after compare two date.

**Please Try This**

```
$last_day = '2017-11-01';
$end = strtotime('18/03/2017');
$last_day = strtotime(date('d/m/Y', strtotime($last_day)));

 if($last_day < $end){
    echo "Is closed";
 }else{
    echo "Is Open";
 }
```

Comment: Code dumps to not make for good answers. You should explain how and why this solves their problem. You should read, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @JohnConde Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all

try this

```
$last_day = '2017-11-01';
$end = '18/03/2017';
echo $last_day = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($fechas['last_day']));
if($last_day < $end){ echo "Is closed";}
else{ echo "Is Open";}
```

It will show you the correct value of $last date. And you can easily understand the problem.
or 
You can convert both dates into timestamp and compare them.

```
$last_day = strtotime('2017-11-01');
$end = strtotime('18/03/2017');
$last_day = strtotime($fechas['last_day']);
if($last_day < $end){ echo "Is closed";}
else{ echo "Is Open";}
```

Answer (score -2):

You cannot compare between string and date. Please convert both variable to date.

Comment: this is a very poor/low-quality answer.

Comment: the least you can do is to show to do the *Please convert both variable to date*

Comment: @Fred-ii- : oh, ok